# Creating Global Email Server with single domain

Tags: dovecot

I have Postfix/Devocet Email server in a US location, and I would like to create a second email server in the India region but the domain name should be XXYYZZ.COM for both the servers. In the API we are finding the user's location, based on the location I will redirect the Emails.

If the user from US/India tries to create an Email box, India user mails need to redirect to the India server and US user mails need to redirect to the US server using a single domain user1@xxyyzz.com.

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour Nanda,

I understand what you are looking for and it is perfectly possible via proxying which dovecot itself can do.

All you need is extra servers which will act as proxy in front of those you use as backend (US server and India server).

Since I have not much information about your backend, I suggest you read about:

- Dovecot proxy (https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/authentication/proxies/)
- IMAP+POP proxying (https://wiki1.dovecot.org/HowTo/ImapProxy)
- LMTP proxying (https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/protocols/lmtp_server/).

> If the user from US/India tries to create an Email box

By explicitly setting a "host" attribute for each user in your passdb backend (at account creation), you should be able to redirect all requests to a specific host.